# Angular Universal + Asp Net Core: how to serve static file in virtual directory

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal + Asp Net Core App.

I need to serve static file from a "virtual directory".

On ASP NET side I have:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Configuration["CDN"]),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/cdn"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
        });
```

On Angular Universal side I have tried:

```
app.use(express.static('CDN'));

app.use('/CDN', express.static('C:\path\to\CDN'));
```

But none of these works, I got this error:

```
main-es2015.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'CDN/photot.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing server.ts;

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
if(req.url.indexOf('CDN/')>-1){
    res.sendFile(req.url,{ root: 'C:\\path\\to\\cdn' });
} else {
    res.render('index', { req });
}});
```